# Convert column with pipe delimited data into dummy variables

Tags: r, delimiter

I'm interested in taking a column of a data.frame where the values in the column are pipe delimited and creating dummy variables from the pipe-delimited values.

For example:

Let's say we start with

```
df = data.frame(a = c("Ben|Chris|Jim", "Ben|Greg|Jim|", "Jim|Steve|Ben"))

> df
              a
1 Ben|Chris|Jim
2 Ben|Greg|Jim
3 Jim|Steve|Ben
```

I'm interested in ending up with:

```
df2 = data.frame(Ben = c(1, 1, 1), Chris = c(1, 0, 0), Jim = c(1, 1, 1), Greg = c(0, 1, 0), 
                 Steve = c(0, 0, 1))
> df2
  Ben Chris Jim Greg Steve
1   1     1   1    0     0
2   1     0   1    1     0
3   1     0   1    0     1
```

I don't know in advance how many potential values there are within the field. In the example above, the variable "a" can include 1 value or 10 values.  Assume it is a reasonable number (i.e., < 100 possible values).

Any good ways to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another way is using `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape` package.

splitting the dataframe by column `a` and `fill` it by 0 and `drop` the original column.

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(df, "a", "|", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = T)

#   a_Ben a_Chris a_Greg a_Jim a_Steve
#1     1       1      0     1       0
#2     1       0      1     1       0
#3     1       0      0     1       1
```

Comment: what a great find.

Comment: A lot of great answers -- thank you to everyone.  I like this one the best as it feels simplest.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Here is one option using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "id") %>% 
       mutate(a = strsplit(as.character(a), "\\|")) %>% 
       unnest() %>% table()

#    a
# id  Ben Chris Greg Jim Steve
#  1   1     1    0   1     0
#  2   1     0    1   1     0
#  3   1     0    0   1     1
```

The analogue in base R is:

```
df$a <- as.character(df$a)
s    <- strsplit(df$a, "|", fixed=TRUE)
table(id = rep(1:nrow(df), lengths(s)), v = unlist(s))
```

Data:

```
df = data.frame(a = c("Ben|Chris|Jim", "Ben|Greg|Jim", "Jim|Steve|Ben"))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` after splitting the 'a' column

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$a), "|", fixed = TRUE))
#  Ben Chris Greg Jim Steve
#1   1     1    0   1     0
#2   1     0    1   1     0
#3   1     0    0   1     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method in base R

```
# get unique set of names
myNames <- unique(unlist(strsplit(as.character(df$a), split="\\|")))
# get indicator data.frame
setNames(data.frame(lapply(myNames, function(i) as.integer(grepl(i, df$a)))), myNames)
```

which returns

```
Ben Chris Jim Greg Steve
1   1     1   1    0     0
2   1     0   1    1     0
3   1     0   1    0     1
```

The first line uses `strsplit` to produce a list of names split on the pipe "|", `unlist` and `unique` produce a vector of unique names.  The second line runs through these names with `lapply`, and uses `grepl` to search for the names, which `as.integer` converts into binary integers. The returned list is converted into a data.frame and given column names with `setNames`.