# Get Dummies for multiple values in a single field in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a field with multiple categories separated by a comma. It looks like the following:

```
1] "{TV,\"Wireless Internet\",Kitchen,\"Free Parking on Premises\",\"Pets live on this property\",Dog(s),Heating,\"Family/Kid Friendly\",Washer,Dryer,\"Smoke Detector\",\"Fire Extinguisher\",Essentials,Shampoo,\"Laptop Friendly Workspace\"}"                                                                                                      
[2] "{TV,Internet,\"Wireless Internet\",\"Air Conditioning\",Kitchen,\"Pets Allowed\",\"Pets live on this property\",Dog(s),Heating,\"Family/Kid Friendly\",Washer,Dryer,\"Smoke Detector\",\"Carbon Monoxide Detector\",\"Fire Extinguisher\",Essentials,Shampoo,\"Lock on Bedroom Door\",Hangers,\"Hair Dryer\",Iron}"
```

Is there a way to generate dummies for each category using R? I know there's fastDummies package in R but that's for single categorical field. Any suggestions for multiple categories?

```
Expected output:
 TV Wi-Fi Iron Hangers
 0  1    1    0
 0  0    1    0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add data using `dput`? You can use `cSplit_e` from `splitstackshape` , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461539/convert-column-with-pipe-delimited-data-into-dummy-variables/39461990#39461990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copy and pasted your data "as is" into a script and applied some regex. Thus, you can pretty much ignore the first part. In the second part the comma separated items are splited and expanded/unlisted for each row and then fed to dcast, which creates a column for each value of "category".

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
DT <- data.table(col = c("{TV,\"Wireless Internet\",Kitchen,\"Free Parking on Premises\",\"Pets live on this property\",Dog(s),Heating,\"Family/Kid Friendly\",Washer,Dryer,\"Smoke Detector\",\"Fire Extinguisher\",Essentials,Shampoo,\"Laptop Friendly Workspace\"}",
                         "{TV,Internet,\"Wireless Internet\",\"Air Conditioning\",Kitchen,\"Pets Allowed\",\"Pets live on this property\",Dog(s),Heating,\"Family/Kid Friendly\",Washer,Dryer,\"Smoke Detector\",\"Carbon Monoxide Detector\",\"Fire Extinguisher\",Essentials,Shampoo,\"Lock on Bedroom Door\",Hangers,\"Hair Dryer\",Iron}")
)

DT[, col2 := col %>%  
  str_remove_all("\\\\") %>% 
  str_remove_all("\"") %>% 
  str_remove_all("\\{|\\}")]

dummies <- DT[, .(category = col2 %>% 
                    str_split(",") %>%
                    unlist(col2)), by = .(row = seq_len(nrow(DT)))]  %>% 
  dcast(row ~ category,
        fun.aggregate = length,
        fill = 0)

dummies

   row Air Conditioning Carbon Monoxide Detector Dog(s) Dryer Essentials Family/Kid Friendly
1:   1                0                        0      1     1          1                   1
2:   2                1                        1      1     1          1                   1
   Fire Extinguisher Free Parking on Premises Hair Dryer Hangers Heating Internet Iron Kitchen
1:                 1                        1          0       0       1        0    0       1
2:                 1                        0          1       1       1        1    1       1
   Laptop Friendly Workspace Lock on Bedroom Door Pets Allowed Pets live on this property Shampoo
1:                         1                    0            0                          1       1
2:                         0                    1            1                          1       1
   Smoke Detector TV Washer Wireless Internet
1:              1  1      1                 1
2:              1  1      1                 1
```